# Projects in Project Browser are disappeared but remain in disk

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Every new day my projects are lost in project browser in eclipse-indigo but remain in disk, so I must import all projects again in every morning. Do you have any idea about this problem?

I can see all projects in ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects

When I open the eclipse, the files which I worked one day ago, make an exception:
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The file does not exist.

Two days ago my eclipse crashed and this problem started probably after this time. Also I found these in error logs:

--> The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

--> Ignored attempt to add saveable that was already registered

--> Unable to create editor ID org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PropertiesFileEditor: The file does not exist.

Comment: Do you use working sets? Is it possible you are viewing a working set and projects are being removed from that. Check the view menu associated with the Project/Package Explorer and make  sure the working set settings are as you like them.

Comment: @FrancisUpton No, I do not use a working set.

Comment: Open up your error log and look for relevant errors.  Paste them above.  You may want to just discard your current workspace and start over again (and re-import all your existing projects).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:
Shut down Eclipse IDE
Remove and backup your `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources` directory

Start Eclipse IDE (with -clean to be super-safe)
Reimport all projects (UPDATE: Just use `File->Import->Existing Project into Workspace` and browse your workspace/project directory)
Enjoy

Source: http://ahtik.com/blog/2008/01/15/eclipse-workspace-fails-to-start-after-crash-quick-fix/